# SharePoint 2013 Managed Navigation - 301 Redirect when Term is Moved?

Tags: 2013, navigation, managed-metadata, internet-sites, managed-navigation

My client has an issue where they are moving terms around within their SharePoint 2013 managed navigation as part of a website restructure. They (understandably) want to ensure any hits to the former friendly URLs are automatically redirected to their new location. So as a simple example their "About" page used to exist at "`/about`" but they've since moved that term to point at "`/company/about`". They would like hits to "`/about`" to be captured intelligently somehow and redirected to the new term URL.

I doubt this is available out of the box but does anyone have any ideas on how to implement a 301 Redirect for this scenario? For instance is there anything similar to the "Event Receiver" concept for when metadata terms are updated/moved/deleted etc.?

I would appreciate your thoughts.
Thanks,
James.

Comment: I just found what looks like it maybe a suitable solution using IIS's rewrite module written by Eric Harlan on his blog: http://www.ericharlan.com/Moss_SharePoint_2007_Blog/using-301-redirect-url-rewrite-module-to-redirect-sharepoint-urls-a236.html

Answer (score 0):

Multiple friendly url's is one of the primary uses for managed navigation. Why do you need a 301 redirect as opposed to multiple mappings?

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn194311.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

> Friendly URLs are URLs that correspond to a term in the navigation term set, and that provide a shorter, more meaningful URL to a page. This makes the URL more useful to visitors to your site, and also improves search engine optimization (SEO) for your site. For example, the URL http://www.contoso.com/products/household/vacuum-cleaner is more meaningful to both users and search engines than the URL http://www.contoso.com/Products/Inventory/Pages/productViewer.aspx?productID=115&name=vacuum%20cleaner&CID=34q327234ef. By default, when you create a new page, a new navigation term is created, and a corresponding friendly URL is created for the page. You can use a single friendly URL to point to a single page. **You can also have multiple friendly URLs that point to the same page, such as a category page.** For example, if you use cross-site publishing to display content from a knowledge base, you can have separate friendly URLs for /kb/manuals, /kb/troubleshooting-guides, and /kb/product-specs that all point to the same category page, Category-KB-Articles.aspx. You do not have to use cross-site publishing to use multiple friendly URLs that point to the same page.

Comment: The example on TechNet refers to having the same underlying ASPX page but then using the URL values to display different content on that same page. It is bad SEO to have multiple URLs pointing to the exact same content. We never solved this one.